# How to find out which user web app is running as?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I'm using HttpPostedFile.SaveAs() in a Web API app. It fails to save with an access denied error if the file already exist.

From this post [HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs method question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292709/httppostedfilebase-saveas-method-question), that should not be the case. If I manually delete the file, all is well.

Is this issue related to permissions?

When I look in Explorer at the users who have permissions on this folder, there are four. Only my user doesn't have write permissions. I don't think that is the issue because otherwise, I wouldn't be able to write at all correct?

This is running on my dev machine.

Comment: Have you checked permissions on the file that is being overwritten? Specifically, is the read-only flag set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if the web app is running under IIS or IIS Express.
If your'e running from visual studio by default it on IIS Express, in that case the user is the user which ran Visual Studio (you). Be sure to run VS as administrator.
Under IIS the user is determand by the user running the Application pool which the app is attached to. By default a new special user is created for you which be named after the app-pool. You may change it at:
IIS-> Application Pool -> Right click the correct apppool -> advanced -> change the identity.

The easyest way to find out the actual user is to look at windows Task Manager (ctrl+shift+esc), go to Details, look for w3wp.exe and look at the username.

Comment: Did you mean "Identity" under the app pool advanced settings? I don't see "user".  Identity = ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Comment: Exactly. Change the identity. Enter your username and password.